# DateTime picker format is different to DateTime format in Razor component

Tags: jquery, razor, bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker, datetime-format

Spent now a few hours already. How to achive same format in Datepicker like in Razor component?

https://github.com/rmoergeli/BlazorAppDateTimeFormatIssue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can format datetime in razor:

```
@Model.DateField.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
```

Don't know what calendar plugins you're using but you can try [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/)

Comment: __<input type="date" class="form-control" @bind-value="DateTimeObject" />__


"input type" is "date". Doesn't work when bind-value is a string. If "input type" is text, no Datepicker is coming up.

Comment: From BlazorAppDateTimeFormatIssue/Pages/Index.razor, try @date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")

Comment: Index.razor is correct, it's "de-CH" format. But Datepicker in modal window is wrong format. Of course I could make both "wrong". But it should be "de-CH" format.